# What are "private Amazon CloudWatch URLs" & do I need OpenSSL for the AWS SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, openssl, sdk

The [AWS SDK for PHP getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_requirements.html) mentions:

> To use the AWS SDK for PHP, you must be using PHP version 5.5.0 or
> later with the SimpleXML PHP extension enabled. If you need to sign
> **private Amazon CloudWatch URLs**, you also need the OpenSSL PHP
> extension.

1. What are *private Amazon CloudWatch URLs*?
2. Is OpenSSL required when using the AWS SDK for PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that looks like a typographical error in the documentation as *private Amazon CloudWatch URLs* do not exist.

It probably meant to say *sign Amazon CloudFront URLs for private distributions* which you can find more about [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) & in specific to PHP, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html).

And no - if you do not need to create signed URLs, there should be no need for the OpenSSL PHP extension when using the AWS SDK for PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree with your opinion.